# Download private_key.pem when using ansible os_keypair

Tags: ansible, openstack, private-key, ansible-tower

I'm using ansible os_keypair module towards Openstack, through AWX, to create a new keypair:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Create new keypair, ask for the name in survey 
    os_keypair:
      cloud: rhosp
      state: present
      name: "{{ survey_keypair_name }}"
    register: result

  - name: Show only private key to copy it in .pem
    debug: var=result.key.private_key
```

When creating a new keypair from Horizon I can download the private_key.pem. How can I retrieve that through ansible module?

Thanks to the register/debug modules I can see output in job execution and copy-paste it manually to a file, but it's a ugly one-line output and it would be nice to have it already in file format.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry, the answer was somehow hidden here: [Why is module os_keypair not returning private_key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/784981/why-is-module-os-keypair-not-returning-private-key?rq=1)

I removed the `debug` task and added the `local_action: module: copy` one.
The key will be downloaded inside awx_task docker container on AWX host, while I need it also locally on my desktop, I will get it somehow (out of the scope of the question).